# Melhor método para categorias via php e mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estou criando um sistema com php + mysql. É um tipo de rede social.

Estou na parte de planejamento do banco de dados e com uma duvida sobre a melhor maneira de gravar, por exemplo, as habilidades do indivíduo.

Exemplo:

Nome: Fulano
Idade: 30
Habilidades: php, mysql, css

Cada "habilidade" tem um cadastro especifico, com descrição foto etc. Portanto, preciso que a pessoa entre na 'página' da habilidade em questão e "curta" ou "siga" e então isso apareça no perfil dela.

Pensei em manter essas 'habilidades' separadas por virgula no banco de dados da pessoa. Assim, na hora de listar, uso explode() e posso inclusive fazer com que cada palavra seja um link que leve a uma seleção de pessoas com mesmas habilidades etc... Até aí, ok. Mas e pra cadastrar/editar/apagar esses dados? Não quero que a pessoa escreva qualquer coisa alí, só adicione via "curtir/seguir"... e isso está ficando complexo de executar... Adicionar ",css" quando a pessoa seguir "css" é uma boa estratégia, ou tem algum método mais recomendado?

Comment: Visto que utilizará um banco relacional, por que não utilizar as relações entre as tabelas?

Answer (score 1):

Use relações entre tabelas à seu favor para resolver esse problema.

Crie uma tabela para habilidades:

```
CREATE TABLE habilidades (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nome VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    descricao TEXT NOT NULL
)
```

E outras quaisquer informações que `habilidades` possuiria, depois relacione o usuário com a habilidade.

```
CREATE TABLE usuario_habilidade (
    usuario int NOT NULL,
    habilidade int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (usuario, habilidade),
    FOREIGN KEY (usuario) REFERENCES SuaTabelaDeUsuario(id)
    FOREIGN KEY (habilidade) REFERENCES habilidades(id)
);
```

Dessa forma, sempre que quiser adicionar uma habilidade ao usuário, apenas adicione um registro a tabela `usuario_habilidade`.